# Single Domain with Single Database with orchestral/tenanti

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to setup a multi tenant architecture such that there will a single domain and a single database to be used for tenants.

But every tenant will have its own schema associated to it. For this, I will use prefix for every table which is required to fetched from database.

Ex. 
there are 2 tenants - T1 and T2
There are 4 tables for each tenant.

In the database, it should be

t1_table_a
t1_table_b
t1_table_c
t1_table_d

t2_table_a
t2_table_b
t2_table_c
t2_table_d

Comment: What was atual problema?

Comment: Actually, I am unable to understand how we can implement this with any package of laravel or may be the package orchestral/tenanti. 

I tried with tenanti, it does not seems to have much information for the package.

Comment: I've already implemented and it's just simple..! Either P.M me or I'll post an answer when I get time

Comment: Please suggest how can you help me :)